# Scala - How to split the probability column (column of vectors) that we obtain when we fit the GMM model to the data in to two separate columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to do the following:

```
+-----+-------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|label|features                 |prediction|probability                                |
+-----+-------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|0.0  |(3,[],[])                |0         |[0.9999999999999979,2.093996169658831E-15] |
|1.0  |(3,[0,1,2],[0.1,0.1,0.1])|0         |[0.999999999999999,9.891337521299582E-16]  |
|2.0  |(3,[0,1,2],[0.2,0.2,0.2])|0         |[0.9999999999999979,2.0939961696578572E-15]|
|3.0  |(3,[0,1,2],[9.0,9.0,9.0])|1         |[2.093996169659668E-15,0.9999999999999979] |
|4.0  |(3,[0,1,2],[9.1,9.1,9.1])|1         |[9.89133752128275E-16,0.999999999999999]   |
|5.0  |(3,[0,1,2],[9.2,9.2,9.2])|1         |[2.0939961696605603E-15,0.9999999999999979]|
+-----+-------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Convert the above dataframe to have two more columns: `prob1` & `prob2`
Each column having the corresponding values as present in the `probability` column.

I found similar questions - one in PySpark and the other in Scala. I do not know how to translate the PySpark code and I am getting an error with the Scala code.

PySpark Code:

```
split1_udf = udf(lambda value: value[0].item(), FloatType())
split2_udf = udf(lambda value: value[1].item(), FloatType())

output2 = randomforestoutput.select(split1_udf('probability').alias('c1'), split2_udf('probability').alias('c2'))
```

Or to append these columns to the original dataframe:

```
randomforestoutput.withColumn('c1', split1_udf('probability')).withColumn('c2', split2_udf('probability'))
```

Scala Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val getPOne = udf((v: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) => v(1))
model.transform(testDf).select(getPOne($"probability"))
```

I get the following error when I run the Scala code:

```
scala> predictions.select(getPOne(col("probability"))).show(false)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(probability)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, '`probability`' is of vector type.;;
'Project [UDF(probability#39) AS UDF(probability)#135]
+- Project [label#0, features#1, prediction#34, UDF(features#1) AS probability#39]
   +- Project [label#0, features#1, UDF(features#1) AS prediction#34]
      +- Relation[label#0,features#1] libsvm
```

I am currently using Scala 2.11.11 and Spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you are trying to `split` `probability` column into two columns `prob1` and `prob2`. If thats the case then a simple `array` functionality with `withColumn` should solve your issue.

```
predictions
  .withColumn("prob1", $"probability"(0))
  .withColumn("prob2", $"probability"(1))
  .drop("probability")
```

You can find [more functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) that can help you in the future to be applied to `dataframes`.

**Edited**

I created a temp `dataframe` to match with your `column` as

```
val predictions = Seq(Array(1.0,2.0), Array(2.0939961696605603E-15,0.9999999999999979), Array(Double.NaN,Double.NaN)).toDF("probability")
+--------------------------------------------+
|probability                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
|[1.0, 2.0]                                  |
|[2.0939961696605603E-15, 0.9999999999999979]|
|[NaN, NaN]                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

And I applied the above `withColumns` which resulted

```
+----------------------+------------------+
|prob1                 |prob2             |
+----------------------+------------------+
|1.0                   |2.0               |
|2.0939961696605603E-15|0.9999999999999979|
|NaN                   |NaN               |
+----------------------+------------------+
```

**Schema mismatch Edit**

Now that since `Vector` `schema` of your `probability` column doesn't match with above solution of `arrayType` `schema`, above solution shall not work in your condition. Please use the following solution.

You will have to create `udf` functions and return the value as expected as

```
   val first = udf((v: Vector) => v.toArray(0))
    val second = udf((v: Vector) => v.toArray(1))
    predictions
      .withColumn("prob1", first($"probability"))
      .withColumn("prob2", second($"probability"))
      .drop("probability")
```

I hope you get the desired result.

Comment: The correct `Vector` data type to use is `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`

Thanks a lot for your help and patience! Really appreciate it!